# Rewrite Spring configuration using java annotations instead xml for import statement with SpEl

Tags: java, spring

I have old Spring project that is using xml configuration.
And I want rewrite this configuration using `java annotations` (for some reasons).
In this `xml` configuration I have this creepy code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns....>
    <!-- ... -->
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/${service.loader:service}-loader.xml" />
    <!-- ... -->
</beans>
```

**How I may rewrite this import statement using java annotations?**

```
@Configuration
@Import({
     // TODO What do I need write here?
})
public class SpringConfig {
     // ...
}
```

**Update:**

Note: I want rewrite all xml files, and I need import java class (from property or default).
I think I need condition statement for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Configuration
public class Loader {
  /*configurations in classpath:/spring/${service.loader:service}
  -loader.xml file */

}

@Configuration
@Import({Loader.class})
public class SpringConfig {
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to import from xml basedc onfiguration you may use the below tag to import resource in annotation based spring configuration.

```
@ImportResource("/spring/${service.loader:service}-loader.xml")
```

But if you are converting every context xml into corresponding annotation based `@Conguration` then you should do it with below tag

```
@Import(OtherConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: thanks, but mean how I may import another java configuration using condition? Or SpEl?

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-boot then you can do something like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:myconfig.xml")
public class MyClasss{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); //Up and running
   }

}
```